# How to update a sheet in Coldfusion

Tags: excel, coldfusion

I have a template on Sheet1 in my Excel file. I can open it, put data into it but I cannot save back onto Sheet1.

```
<cfspreadsheet 
        action="update" 
        filename = "#theFileCopy#" 
        name = "a" 
        sheetName="Sheet1">
```

Infuriatingly, for an update statement, this code tells me Sheet1 already exists. I know it exists, I want to overwrite it. I cant even use action=write to write out the spreadsheet to an entirely new file because it gives me a null pointer exception. I even tried adding the sheet to the same file on a different name and deleting sheet1 but that fails as well, another null pointer! I'm getting frustrated. Why on earth isnt any of this working?

```
Stack Trace
at cfRelocationForm2ecfc1823847668$funcPRODUCERELOCATIONFORM.runFunction(xxx/RelocationForm.cfc:152) 
 at cfRelocationForm2ecfc1823847668$funcPRODUCERELOCATIONFORM.runFunction(xxx/RelocationForm.cfc:152) 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString.toCTFont(XSSFRichTextString.java:458)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString.getFontOfFormattingRun(XSSFRichTextString.java:397)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.ColumnHelper.getColumnWidth(ColumnHelper.java:368)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(XSSFSheet.java:337)
    at coldfusion.excel.Excel.autoResize(Excel.java:1336)
    at coldfusion.excel.Excel.autoResize(Excel.java:1327)
    at coldfusion.excel.Excel.writeExcel(Excel.java:4824)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.SpreadSheetTag.writeToExcel(SpreadSheetTag.java:237)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.SpreadSheetTag.doStartTag(SpreadSheetTag.java:157)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2799)
    at 

cfRelocationForm2ecfc1823847668$funcPRODUCERELOCATIONFORM.runFunction(xxx\RelocationForm.cfc:152)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:518)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:660)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:469)
    at coldfusion.filter.ComponentFilter.invoke(ComponentFilter.java:193)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:442)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112)
    at coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:30)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.invoke(CFCServlet.java:155)
    at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.doGet(CFCServlet.java:289)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:414)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:204)
    at 

org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The lines causing the error

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#theFileCopy#" name="spreadSheetVar" >
    <cfset spreadsheetRemoveSheet(spreadsheetVar,"Relocation Form")> 
    <cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#theFileCopy#"  name="spreadsheetVar" overwrite="true" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cfspreadsheet read will do xlsx files but write will not. Maddeningly. This is where the null pointer was occurring, basically whenever i tried to write the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

action="write" combined with overwrite="true" should do it. As per Cf docs, UPDATE does not allow to modify existing sheet, ikt just allow you to add new sheet to your excel. So you will have to use action write with overwrite attribute.

Comment: Action= Write doesnt work either. If i use spreadsheetnew i can do a write but if i read in a spreadsheet, edit it and then write it i get a nullpointer

Comment: In fact, just attempting to read a spreadsheet and then write it out anywhere at all causes a null pointer.

Comment: Can you provide the error stack and code block being pointed on error stack?

Comment: Thanks for providing error stack, can you provide line numbered 151-152-153 from RelocationForm.cfc. If possible the whole block of code, it is looking like something else is going wrong.

Comment: I just had some luck, by the time that the deleting occurs there are 4 sheets in the spreadsheet, Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 and Relocation Form. All i want left is relocation form but deleting all the other sheets causes the null pointer, it doesnt matter what order i do it in. If there were no sheets left Coldfusion tends to give an error like "Spreadsheet must have at least 1 sheet" so its not that.

Comment: I am sorry, but I ran into some other problems, bugs probably. Will ask that in a separate question. Anyhow after playing a bit, I found that it will not allow removal of first sheet. Do you have more than one sheet in your excel? If not, you need not use spreadsheetRemoveSheet and just overwrite the excel after making the changes. I also saw some other posts where issue with this function has been discussed. One such link, if it can help is https://www.mail-archive.com/discussion@acfug.org/msg07918.html

Comment: I only want 1 sheet in my spreadsheet. I am reading in a template from an existing spreadsheet and editing it. At this point the first two problems come up. action=update does not allow me to overwrite the sheet that i took the template from meaning that i have to give it a different name. There are three sheets in the existing template so now there are four.

I should really just use action=write and create a new file right? Well no dice on that either. Trying to write any new file with the edited template causes a NullPointerException. Im am totally cornered.